# Java SWT Browser opens download dialog when viewing PDF on Linux

Tags: java, pdf, swt

I have following code which works well on Windows:

```
private void showSelectedPdf() {
    File selected = getSelectedPdf();

    if(selected != null) {
        String path = selected.getAbsolutePath();
        browser.setUrl(path);
    }
}
```

But on Linux it only shows download dialog. It is very strange, because my default browser is Firefox and when i type

```
$ firefox blabla.pdf
```

it opens normal Firefox window with displayed PDF.

Is there any easy way to display PDF with SWT Browser on Windows and Linux?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the browser instantiated as `new Browser(parent, SWT.MOZILLA)` on Linux? And on Windows I would seriously recommend abandoning `Browser` and going with an external tool like IcePDF.

Comment: No, that is giving me an exception.. I probably try IcePDF you mentioned or other library.

Comment: It's giving you an exception because you don't have XULRunner present on your machine. I think that a browser with style `SWT.NONE` always uses Internet Explorer, with which if you open a PDF, it will show a download dialog..

Comment: [This](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserplatforms) is always worth reading when working with SWT `Browser`.